What will PooledConnectionLifetime in HttpClient do with existing connection?
let's say we use HttpClient to make a request and set the PooledConnectionLifetime to 5 seconds as
// C# pseudo code, not in the right format

var socketsHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
{
    PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)  // just for demo purpose
};
public static client = new HttpClient(socketsHandler); // we use a single static `HttpClient`

// takes 3 seconds to finish a request as the server is slow 
client.GetAsync("https://www.slowwebsite.com");  // create a TCP connection and put this connection in a pool

// after 3 seconds , send another request
client.GetAsync("https://www.slowwebsite.com");  // re-use the TCP connection 

so after the first request, a TCP connection is established and pooled, and when we issue the second request, it can re-use the TCP connection.
but in 5th second, the tcp connection is supposed to be closed due to PooledConnectionLifetime being set to 5 seconds.
My question is, will the tcp connection closed immediately (become TIME_WAIT state)? if it get closed immediately , isn't that the second request get interrupted and stopped?
If the tcp connection will not closed immediately and wait for the second request to finish first then the connection is closed, isn't it what IHttpClientFactory does:
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("typicode", c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.slowwebsite.com/");
})
.SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

but according to this article, Scenario 5: Use IHttpClientFactory https://www.mytechramblings.com/posts/dotnet-httpclient-basic-usage-scenarios/#:~:text=Once%20this%20lifetime%20expires%2C%20the,and%20removed%20from%20the%20pool.

TCP connection was closed immediately after the time set by the PooledConnectionLifetime attribute had expired, the expiration of a handler will not promptly dispose of the TCP connection. The expired handler (controlled by SetHandlerLifetime) will be positioned in a distinct pool, which is periodically processed to dispose of handlers only when they become unreachable.

That sounds like in my HttpClient example, the second request will get interrupted and stopped?

It's going to hold open all the connections because you aren't disposing the HttpResponseMessage. Open responses are not disconnected, only connections waiting in the pool.

You need to use PooledConnectionIdleTimeout  to ensure that TCP is closed
private static readonly HttpClient Client = new(new SocketsHttpHandler
    {
        PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
    })

PooledConnectionLifetime is set to 30 minutes, which means that TCP connections will be reused during 30 minutes.
PooledConnectionIdleTimeoutis set to 10 seconds, which means that idle TCP connections will be closed after a maximum of 10 seconds, it doesn’t matter if the PooledConnectionLifetime time has been reached or not.
Source : https://www.mytechramblings.com/posts/dotnet-httpclient-basic-usage-scenarios/
